# SQL Distinct on XML

Tags: c#, sql, .net, xml

I have an sql table as follows:

```
 AID  | BID  |  STIME     | XML                   | PKEY 
 1234 | 5678 | 2012-04-12 | <XML>duplicate</XML>  | 34555
 1234 | 5678 | 2012-04-12 | <XML>duplicate</XML>  | 34555
 1593 | 5847 | 2012-03-13 | <XML>valid</XML>      | 89564
```

There are duplicate rows  and I need to eliminate them. My final aim is to get the XML row (it's of XML datatype) concat XML column and pull from my C# application.

At SQL level i have tried the below:

```
Select Distinct XML from Table
where AID = '1234'
for XML Auto
```

I get an error:

> THe XML data type cannot be selected as DISTINCT because it is not
>   comparable

Comment: `DISTINCT CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), XML)`. Not particularly efficient, of course. Shredding your XML and `DISTINCT`ing that might be faster, depending on your data.

Comment: May I request please provide a brief example

Comment: In your example the duplicate XML rows are also duplicate in every other column.  Could you just compare all those other columns and eliminate duplicates based on that?

Comment: The code I've given is literal (`SELECT DISTINCT CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), XML) FROM [Table]`). I can't give an example of how to shred your XML because you haven't given a representative sample. Your rows don't *literally* contain `<XML>duplicate</XML>`, do they? You can use [`value()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/xml/value-method-xml-data-type) to get at the data inside.

Comment: @JeroenMostert: THanks it works :)

Answer (score 1):

Just to expand on Jeroen Mostert's comments

**Example**

```
Select XML = convert(XML,AsString)
 From (
        Select Distinct AsString = convert(nvarchar(max),XML )
         From YourTable
         Where AID = '1234'
      ) A
```

**Returns the XML as**

```
<XML>duplicate</XML>
```

Comment: Hi, this code doesn't work. I have tried Jeroen's code that works, but this doesn't. It gives me an error.

Comment: @user726720 given your sample data it DOES work.  Just curious what was the error?

Comment: @user726720 this was actually tested because I have never had to select distinct XML so I was curious.  Thus the upvote on your question.... It was unique.

Comment: `Type XML` is not a defined system type

Comment: Thanks for the giggle. Think about what you typed there.

Comment: What I typed is correct, as I'm using the same with other scripts. I have cross checked it before posting back.